# Why doesn't my @BeforeClass method run when executing a subclass test method?

Tags: java, junit4

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.3 and JUnit 4.12.

I have a test class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeAll() {
    //start a server for all tests to hit
  }

  @Before
  public void before() {
    //init a common request object for each test
  }

  @Test
  public void itShouldHaveSomeCommonProperty() {
    //check some common thing
  }

  public class SomeSubTestClass {
    @Before
    public void before() {
      //do some test case-specific setup
    }

    public class SomeOtherSubTestClass {
      @Test
      public void itShouldDoSomething() {
        //hit the service and assert something about the result
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I tell IntelliJ to run the class, everything works as expected.  However, if I want to just run the `itShouldDoSomething` test (which I'm doing by setting up a run configuration that targets the `SomeOtherSubTestClass` class), the `beforeAll` method is not executed.  Both of the `before` methods are executed in the correct order, but not the static `beforeAll` method.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug.

The `beforeAll` method is static and therefore tied to the class and not the instance. This is why it is not executed when calling tests in inner classes or sub-classes.

To ensure it being called you would have to define a `@BeforeClass` method in each of your inner classes which then call the method on the outer class.

Comment: Argh.  That's really irritating, given that enclosing `@Before` methods are called as expected.  I feel like this is an instance where the Principle of Least Astonishment was violated.  Thanks for the answer, though.